# index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list in C#

Tags: c#

I am getting below error

> ndex (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list

`spec.obscLabel` has value null and `consOrder.Location.Code` returns value.

```
var template = string.Format(_Services.GetSettingValue("ZP", spec.obscLabel ?? consOrder.Location.Code));
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error is clear, the index you are passing to `GetSettingValue` is out of bounds for it, use your debugger to find the cause and fix your bug.

Comment: `string.Format("", [])` will replace any `{0}` in the format string with a value from the second parameter. Which you haven't supplied. As if you had written `string.Format(..., new object[0]);`